# Decompose hermitian matrix into product of vector and it's conjugate transpose

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

Lets suppose I have a (n x n) hermitian matrix A, defined as a product of (n x m) matrix B and it's hermitian transpose:

A = B*B'

Matrix B is known, it is not structured and is positive definite.

1) How do I decompose matrix A as a product of u*u', where u is a vector of length n?

2) Is it possible to calculate *u* directly from B, without first calculating full matrix A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the singular value decomposition of B.  The eigenvectors of A are the left singular vectors of B, and the eigenvalues of A are the magnitude-squared of the singular values of B.  (In the equations below, ' denotes conjugate transpose.)

B=USV'

A = BB' = USV'(USV')' = USV'VS'U' = USS'U'

Now, with the eigen-decomposition of A, you can express A as the weighted sum of uu', where u are the columns of U (eigenand the weights (eigenvalues) are the diagonal values of SS'.